# Use ffmpeg on windows to convert a set of png images to a set of webp images

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to use this command to convert all .png in the images directory to .webp, but it did not achieve the expected result. Is there any other way to achieve this function?

```
images> (for %i in (*.png) do ffmpeg -i %i %2d.webp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
> (for %i in (*.png) do ffmpeg -i %i %~ni.webp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Install [ffmpeg for Windows](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows), ensure ffmpeg is in your [Path environment variable](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/20496), navigate to the folder where your PNGs are, right-click or shift + right-click and select "Open in Windows Terminal" or "Open PowerShell window here", and finally paste in this command and hit enter:

```sh
md webp; foreach($file in (ls "*.png")){$bn = $file.Basename; $png = $bn + ".png"; $webp = $bn + ".webp"; ffmpeg -i "$png" "webp/$webp"}
```

It will create a separate webp folder then convert all your PNGs and place them into that folder.